# Dynamic getter is not supported for value type [KeyValuePair`2]

Tags: c#, xaml, telerik, windows-phone-8.1, windows-rt

I'm trying the new Telerik Universal UI and I ran in this exception when binding to an `ObservableDictionary<string, int>`.

> System.ArgumentException:Dynamic getter is not supported for value type [KeyValuePair`2]   atTelerik.Universal.Core.DynamicHelper.CreatePropertyValueGetter(Typetype, String propertyName)   atTelerik.Universal.UI.Xaml.Controls.Chart.PropertyNameDataPointBinding.GetValue(Objectinstance)   atTelerik.Universal.UI.Xaml.Controls.Chart.CategoricalSeriesDataSource.InitializeBinding(DataPointBindingEntrybinding)   atTelerik.Universal.UI.Xaml.Controls.Chart.ChartSeriesDataSource.GenerateDataPoint(ObjeHere's the code that I'm using:

I know that I should write to their support forum but it always gives `Error 500` when I'm posting and I'm tired of rewriting my post again.

Here's my code:

(ViewModel)

```
public ObservableDictionary<string, int> MyDict { get; set; }
...
private void UpdateStats()
{
    MyDict.Clear();            
    foreach (var item in Items)
    {
        var dayString = item.When.Date.ToLocalTime().ToString();
        var dayKey = dayString.Split(' ')[0];
        MyDict[dayKey] = (MyDict.ContainsKey(dayKey)) ? MyDict[dayKey] + 1 : 1;                
    }
}
```

(Page)

```
<chart:RadCartesianChart x:Name="lineSeries" 
                         PaletteName="DefaultLight"
                         ClipToBounds="False">
    <chart:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
        <chart:LinearAxis/>
    </chart:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
    <chart:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
        <chart:CategoricalAxis AutoGroup="True"
                               PlotMode="OnTicks"/>
    </chart:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
    <chart:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding MyDict}">
        <chart:LineSeries.CategoryBinding>
            <chart:PropertyNameDataPointBinding PropertyName="Key"/>
        </chart:LineSeries.CategoryBinding>
        <chart:LineSeries.ValueBinding>
            <chart:PropertyNameDataPointBinding PropertyName="Value"/>
        </chart:LineSeries.ValueBinding>
    </chart:LineSeries>
</chart:RadCartesianChart>
```

Any idea on how to solve this?
I'd like to keep things done in XAML instead of writing code within the page.

Answer (score 0):

;edited; my bad misread the error at night

I don't believe Telerik provided Xaml support for dictionary bindings with their LineSeries control so you're probably limited to code-behind. Sorry!

Comment: Still the same exception :\

Comment: I ended up writing a wrapper class and binding the chart to a `List<CustomWrapperClass>`